# How to scan and respond to a user's input?

Tags: java

Creating a simple ATM menu with few options on it.

Want to know how to let user inputs something to select the options, and then the codes can respond to the input.

For example, "readLine(string)"

Following is my code:

```
public class Menu 
{   
    private String menuText;
    private int optionCount;

    public Menu()
    {
        menuText = "";
        optionCount = 0;
    }

    public void addOption(String option)
    {
        optionCount = optionCount + 1;
        menuText = menuText + optionCount + ") " + option + "\n";
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(menuText);
    }
}

public class MenuDemo{
    public MenuDemo() 
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Menu mainMenu = new Menu();
        mainMenu.addOption("Log In Account");
        mainMenu.addOption("Deposit Check");
        mainMenu.addOption("Help");
        mainMenu.addOption("Quit");
        mainMenu.display(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the user Input with Scanner class. And then with switch statement do your required actions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Menu 
{   
    private String menuText;
    private int optionCount;

    public Menu()
    {
        menuText = "";
        optionCount = 0;
    }

    public void addOption(String option)
    {
        optionCount = optionCount + 1;
        menuText = menuText + optionCount + ") " + option + "\n";
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(menuText);
    }
}

public class MenuDemo{
    public MenuDemo() 
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Menu mainMenu = new Menu();
        mainMenu.addOption("1. Log In Account");
        mainMenu.addOption("2. Deposit Check");
        mainMenu.addOption("3. Help");
        mainMenu.addOption("4. Quit");
        mainMenu.display();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Choice: ");
        String i = input.nextLine();

        switch(i){

        case "1":
            //do something
            System.out.println("User Entered 1 : " + i);
            break;
        case "2":
            //do something
            System.out.println("User Entered 2 : " + i);
            break;
        case "3":
            //do something
            System.out.println("User Entered 3 : " + i);
            break;
        case "4":
            //do something
            System.out.println("User Entered 4 : " + i);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Quit" + i);
        }


    }

}
```